# Error in mysql. Failed to add the foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS blocks (
  serialSilos VARCHAR(32),
  idBlock VARCHAR(32),

  PRIMARY KEY (serialSilos, idBlock),
  FOREIGN KEY (serialSilos) REFERENCES silos(serialSilos) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
);


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS view_policies (
  email VARCHAR(128),
  block VARCHAR(32),
 

  PRIMARY KEY (email, block),
  FOREIGN KEY (email) REFERENCES users(email) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY (block) REFERENCES blocks(idBlock) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
 );
```

and generate this errors:

> ERROR 1822 (HY000): Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint 'view_policies_ibfk_2' in the referenced table 'blocks'

there are other tables but they are irrelevant. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

You have a combine key in blocks, when you doon't want ti reference the primary key.

Use  a key for idBlock or even better use the primary key

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS blocks (
  serialSilos VARCHAR(32),
  idBlock VARCHAR(32),
KEY (idBlock),
  PRIMARY KEY (serialSilos, idBlock),
  FOREIGN KEY (serialSilos) REFERENCES silos(serialSilos) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE

);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the following command and check the detail error.

```
SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS
```

---

It should be the InnoDB constraints problem.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

> InnoDB permits a foreign key to reference any index column or group of columns. However, in the referenced table, there must be an index where the referenced columns are the **first columns** in the same order.

Therefore, if you change the order of the columns in reference table - `blocks`. It should allow the `block` column in `view_policies` to refer `idBlock`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS blocks (
  idBlock VARCHAR(32),
  serialSilos VARCHAR(32),

  PRIMARY KEY (idBlock, serialSilos),
  FOREIGN KEY (serialSilos) REFERENCES silos(serialSilos) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```